# Changing classes for current page nav link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry I don't know what the title should be so someone please change it to best fit my question.

Basically, I have a list like this:

```
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
```

depeding on what page I am on (Home, About, Contant), I want the corresponding `<li>` tag to have `class="active"` attribute. What the best way to do this?

I have a class variable @title set to whatever page is being navigated.

Comment: One question: Which way do you demiter on what page you are currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`link_to_unless_current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) helper. You'll need slightly different css, but it is worth it. You won't have to worry about `@title` etc, and you won't get confusing links to the current page. For example, use:

```
<nav>
  <% [["Home", :home], ["About", :about], ["Contact", :contact]].each do |name,url| %>
    <li><%= link_to_unless_current(name, url) %></li>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

And then, suppose you want the "active" case to be bold and green, use this CSS:

```
nav li {  /* active case */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
nav li a {  /* normal, link case */
  font-weight: normal;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This wont to it because he wants the "way" to the current page not only the current page viewed but unly the current page highlighted!

Comment: @davidb: you're right, but I'm hoping my answer gets closer to the rails-way of achieving his real goals. (though perhaps it doesn't)

Answer (score 12):

Use `current_page?(options)` to know if the controller/action/params corresponds to the url, and switch class based on that, e.g. with an helper like this (untested):

```
 def nav_item(name, path)
   if current_page?(path)
     @title = name
   end
   content_tag('li', :class=>(current_page?(path) ? 'active' : nil) ){link_to(name,path)}
 end

<%= nav_item 'Home', root_path %>
<%= nav_item 'About', about_path %>
<%= nav_item 'Contact', contact_path %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a before filter in `application_controller.rb` to instantiate current controller and action.

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :instantiate_controller_and_action_names

def instantiate_controller_and_action_names
  @current_action = action_name
  @current_controller = controller_name
end
```

Define a helper to generate the link with the css class set if the action and controller of that link are current.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def section_link_to(name, url_options, html_options = {})
    if action.eql?(@current_action) and controller.eql?(@current_controller)
      link_to(name, url_options, html_options, :class => 'current')
    else
      link_to(name, url_options, html_options)
    end
  end
end
```

Define your css to highlight the active link:

```
nav li.active {  /* current */
  font-weight: bold;
  background: green;
}
```

Hope this helps.